# jQuery dataTables : How do I replace the default page length menu select box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Is it possible to replace default datatables select box (page length menu) with a bootstrap type select?

Currently datatables shows a typical select box with different length options we provide in `aLengthMenu` option. I want to change it to something nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed possible. The length menu is an ordinary `<select>` injected into a `.dataTables_length` `<div>`. I dont know what bootstrap select wrapper exactly you have in mind, so picked up [**bootstrap select**](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) as it was first hit in google.

Simply include `bootstrap-select.js` and `bootstrap-select.css` to your project, and after dataTables initialization transform the default `<select>` to something nicer :

```js
$(".dataTables_length select").selectpicker({
    width : '80px'
});
```

[image]

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/L0vnvrc5/**